# Node.js route regex

Tags: node.js, regex, parameters, path, routes

i want a route url to be like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/uploader/:path
```

The moment is that `path` can be `''` => `http://localhost:3000/uploader/` or string containing slashes like this `aaa/bbb/ccc` => `http://localhost:3000/api/uploader/aaa/bbb/ccc`

I wrote something like this for empty case

```
http://localhost:3000/api/uploader/:path?
```

How can I write regex for many slashes, so the `req.params === /aaa/bbb/ccc` ?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/QYeXGl/1) help?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using express and answer below.

What you're looking for is the `*` wildcard.

Try this and check it out:

```
router.get('/uploader/?*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.originalUrl);
});
```

You should see the request url back to you so you can confirm.

Edit: I'm changing the wildcard with the question mark to accept baseUrl too***

Tell me if anything else, but that should do it. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer actually it worked with ?* for empty case, update your question and I'll check it as right answer.)

Comment: Which node.js version are you using?

Comment: latest  stable 12.18.0

Comment: I'm testing on my tests server and it works even without the question mark. I'll update with demo images

Comment: try just localhost:3000/uploader/ the api won't be found.

Comment: Did you try just this get route? `'/uploader*'`

Comment: That's valid sintax, but i would not suggest to use /uploader* because it would take "EVERYTHING" starting with /uploader, even something weird like `/uploaderdsjiucxu9e12312@#|[]{isada` and that's just not right. I updated before with the question mark

Comment: That's why i validate the path  in my middleware.)